# multer 'filesLeft[file.fieldname]' undefined

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, multer

I am new with multer and I am trying to upload a file to express server with multer, the client side is ReactJS:

express - 4.15.2
multer - 1.3.0
axios - 0.16.1
react - 15.5.4

the client side (ReactJS):

```
<form onSubmit={this.onFilesUpload} enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' ref={(input) => this.filesInput = input} name='inputFile'/>
    <button type='submit' >upload</button>
</form>
```

I am sending the file in a form data:

```
var data = new FormData();
const files = this.filesInput.files;
for(var key in files) {
     if (files.hasOwnProperty(key) && files[key] instanceof File) {
          data.append(key, files[key]);
        }
    }
```

in the server side:

```
const express = require('express'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      cors = require('cors'),
      router = require('./routes/router'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      multer = require('multer'),
      app = express();
....
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(multer({dest: './public/uploads/}).single('inputFile));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
router(app);
```

i am getting the LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE exception from multer module code - 
node_module\multer\index.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix the issue, the client side code was changed:

```
var data = new FormData();
const inputFile = this.filesInput.files[0];
data.append('file', inputFile);
```